# Вопрос по ViewModel в MVVM

Tags: android, kotlin, viewmodel

Есть код:

```
private val coffeeViewModel: CoffeeViewModel by viewModel()
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, для чего нужна конструкция `by viewModel()`

о `by` я нашёл следующую информацию:
делегирует реализацию интерфейса другому объекту
делегирует реализацию методов доступа для свойства другому объекту

Но что, как и для чего делигируется в этом случае, я так и не понял

Comment: by viewModels() - делегат, которые прячет за собой создание вьюмодели - там уже dagger, hilt и тому подобное используется, которые отвечают за создание и жизненный цикл вьюмодели.

Comment: @vitidev, спасибо!)